# What does 最早将于 mean in 最早将于本周二提起联邦诉讼?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand 最早将于 in the following snippet:

> 在很多业内人士看来，诉讼将是字节跳动创始人张一鸣的唯一选择。而媒体消息称，在这场封杀中，TikTok发起了首次反击，**最早将于**本周二提起联邦诉讼，挑战特朗普在美国封禁该视频共享服务的行政命令。
> <sub>[风暴中的张一鸣：外界骂他软弱 员工赞他理性](https://www.sohu.com/a/412475339_237556), 11 August 2020.</sub>

Clearly 最早 means "earliest", but I don't understand 将于 at all.

> [My translation:] According to many people in the industry, a lawsuit is ByteDance founder [Zhang Yiming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhang_Yiming)'s only choice.  And media information states, under this shut-out, Tiktok launched the first counterattack: 最早将于 this Tuesday raised a federal lawsuit, challenging Trump's executive order, a USA-wide ban on the aforementioned video sharing service.

**Question**: What does 最早将于 mean in the above snippet?

Comment: It's pretty straight forward.  最早 earliest.  将于 will be (at/on/in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (TikTok)最早将于本周二提起联邦诉讼.
>
> (TikTok) will file a federal lawsuit as early as this Tuesday.

"File a federal lawsuit" means "提起联邦诉讼", so "最早将于本周二" means "will... as early as this Tuesday".

结构是: **will do sth. as early as...**

will: 将.

as early as... : 最早于, 后加时间.

do sth. : 即要做的那件事, 在本文中指提起联邦诉讼.

Comment: Not to challenge here, but just to clarify.  The Chinese text 最早将于本周二提起联邦诉讼 means the earliest day to file a federal lawsuit is this Tuesday.(implying it could also be Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, or later on).  Does "as early as this Tuesday" also imply it could be later days(e.g. Wednesday, …)? I'm not sure about this English here, so just want to check.

Comment: Yeah. TikTok maybe can't file a federal lawsuit on Tuesday, probably they will do it on Wednesday or later.